# sharing common lookup in memory data across mappers : Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, lookup, in-memory

I have 30+ mappers and each mapper uses common lookup data which is in-memeory map. 
In each mapper I have to load this lookup data in setup function. I compute this lookup data by querying  and computations on Hbase tables and or or some rdbms database. As I am doing same thing from each mapper this above common task get executed 30 times in each mapper.

Is there anyway by which I can compute that lookup data prior submitting the mapReduce job and set somewhere so that from mappes I can directly go and fetch that value(in memory structure). store somewhere in configuration etc... Lookup generation is heavy task and this takes lot of time.

If it would have been a lookup file I would have used distributed cache but its dynamic computation and not stored in file.

Please suggest any solution to this common problem ?

Comment: any solutions for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you generate the data and then store in HDFS, linked with the distributed cache?

Another trick you could employ (if you are using JVM re-use, and a small-ish cluster) is to make the lookup map static in your mapper, and then perform a not-null check in your set, thus only calculating the data in the first map instance for that tasktracker.